# Mockito and JUnit not found

Tags: android, junit, kotlin, mockito

I have a very old project that has started out as a an eclipse project and is now gradle/ android studio

Currently I have just one test which is stored in the path

`src/test/java/`

I have the below gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    ext.latest_google_version = '27.1.1'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/anko' }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'



kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines 'enable'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/anko' }
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-support-v4:0.4.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.3"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$latest_google_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$latest_google_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$latest_google_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:$latest_google_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$latest_google_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'

    // UnitTest frameworks
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.0"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8"

    // androidTest frameworks
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
//            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
//            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
//            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
//            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']

        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

If I run my unit tests with the gradle file as above is I get errors of

```
Unresolved reference: junit 
Unresolved reference: junit 
Unresolved reference: mockito   
Unresolved reference: mockito   
Unresolved reference: mockito   
Unresolved reference: mockito   
Unresolved reference: Mock  
Unresolved reference: Before    
Unresolved reference: MockitoAnnotations    
Unresolved reference: Test  
Unresolved reference: verify    
Unresolved reference: verifyNoMoreInteractions  
Unresolved reference: Test  
Unresolved reference: Test
```

This is effectively everywhere where junit is referenced in the test.

If I change

```
// UnitTest frameworks
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.0"
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8"
```

to

```
// UnitTest frameworks
implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.0"
implementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8"
```

The tests compile but the test runner will complain that the suite of tests is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have your tests in the correct source set?  That would cause the problem you are describing - they should be in `app/src/test/java/com/example/myapp` and you may need to define them explictly in your `build.gradle`

Comment: the tests are at `{project name}/src/test/java/com/example/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for your errors is the configuration

```
main {
    java.srcDirs = ['src']
}
```

Here you define the whole *src* directory as to contain *Java* main sources. The default directory for this would be *src/main/java*.

Since your tests are stored within *src/test/java*, these are contained in the main sources as well and thus you needed to change the configuration from `testImplementation` to `implementation` to compile.

Instead of configuring your source sets manually, you should consider to restructure your project to meet the default setup.

Comment: I have restructured the project to the default, removed the sourceSets and it all works thanks

Answer (score 2):

This kind of error can be caused by configuring your source sets incorrectly. In your `build.gradle` you have the following:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
    //snip
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    androidTest.setRoot('tests')     
}
```

In other words, your Android tests (instrumentation tests) are in `src/tests/java/com/example`. Note you also have the `main` source set configured as all of `src/*` so this is also incorrect - it should be just `src/main`

Make sure you have correctly understood the difference between local unit tests (which normally go in the `test` directory) and instrumented unit tests (which normally go in the `androidTest` directory) and you can also try adding the following closure to your `build.gradle`:

```
main {
    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    java.srcDirs = ['src/main'] 
}

test {
    java.srcDirs = ['src/test']
}
```

Then you may need to perform a Gradle sync, if that doesn't work, you can try `File -> Invalidate caches/restart`.

Good luck!

Comment: // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
            androidTest.setRoot('src/test/java') was a game changer for me, thank you so much, I was trying to add the path to tests to main using "," as a separator.